# Replace certain text in lines with each line another file

Tags: awk, notepad++, find-replace

I have a text file with text of this order;

```
str/4
<</Contents(100 cups)/(Date)
Colour red
<</Contents(080 bowls)/(Date)
Status used
Pack team
<</Contents(200 John)/(Date)
School house
```

And another text file with a list of words in the order;

```
Tree house
Colon format
Same variable
```

Now the question is, how do I search or match the text between **"Contents("**  and  **")"** in each line, ie. **100 cups**, **080 bowls**, **200 John** and replacementreplace it with corresponding lines from my second file? . The final result should look like;

```
str/4
<</Contents(Tree house)/(Date)
Colour red
<</Contents(Colon format)/(Date)
Status used
Pack team
<</Contents(Same variable)/(Date)
School house
```

Comment: Please, don't cross post https://superuser.com/q/1355898/763386

Comment: You can't do that with Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Sorry about cross-posting. Am new to programming, know about scripting yet